# Bootstrap: How to change tab contents and other panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I need to create a grid with a panel for tabs and other panel for an contextual help.

At the moment I have the code to create the panels and the tabs, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 well">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#home" data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#profile" data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home">home tab content</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile tab content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 well">
            <div class="tab-content">
                Here should came the contextual help
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the obligatory [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqmwz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to do it and I'm leaving it here for comments or to help someone trying to do the same:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 well">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#home" data-target="#home, #home_help" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#profile" data-target="#profile, #profile_help" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home">home tab content</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile tab content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3 well">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home_help">home_help content</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="profile_help">profile_help content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AazhZ/